# Export dashboard URL from job

Tags: url, databricks, dashboard, azure-databricks

I have a notebook running as a job in Azure Databricks.  The results are shown in a Databricks dashboard.  I want the dashboard URL to be sent to the team when the run is finished.

How do I retrieve the URL of the dashboard for the current run ?

I know the job ID, I managed to get the base of the URL with

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().browserHostName().toString()
```

and I found one can get the Run ID with

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().currentRunId().toString()
```

but the URL should contain the "Run", which is different than the "Run ID".  Furthermore, the URL doesn’t display a dashboard without some UUID I don’t know how to get.  Where can I get these informations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
run_id = None
url = None
try:
  run_id = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())["tags"]["idInJob"]
  url = f"https://XXX.azuredatabricks.net/?o=YYY#job/11/run/{run_id}/dashboard/ZZZ"
except:
  pass
```

I figured `XXX`, `YYY` and `ZZZ` do not change along runs, you will find them by looking at your sample dashboard.

`run_id` and `url` will stay `None` if the notebook is launched in interactive mode.